# What archive plugin works with W3 total cache?

Tags: plugins, cache, plugin-w3-total-cache

All plugins I've tried makes the page go blank.

I tried so far:

- Smart Archives Reloaded
- Clean Archives Reloaded
- Better Extended Live Archives

Thanks.

Tal

Comment: Can you give some examples of some that are causing the problems?

Comment: Hi Chris - I updated with examples.

Comment: I will take a look.  Maybe @scribu (Author of Smart Archives Reloaded) will see your question and add some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@Tag,**

To answer your question directly, [Smart Archives Reloaded](http://scribu.net/wordpress/smart-archives-reloaded) works with W3 Total Cache.  I have thoroughly tested it on my [test bed](http://chrisolbekson.com/smart-archives/) and it works fine with W3 Total.  I was even able to easily add the js to my minify settings.

Version 2.0 removed the caching from the plugin.  Have you tried it with the latest version?

> No more buggy caching
>
> Older versions of the plugin stored
> the generated HTML in a text file,
> instead of generating it on each page
> load. Unfortunately, this relied on
> two rather unreliable things: file
> permissions and wp-cron. Thus, it was
> the biggest source of problems for
> users. So I decided to remove file
> caching completely.
>
> If you want caching back, the best
> solution is to use a dedicated plugin,
> such as WP Super Cache. It will make
> your entire site load much faster.

It seems that some of the other archive plugins use some sort of caching mechanism which might cause a conflict with a dedicated caching plugin like W3 Total.

Comment: Hello Chris (thank you for the answer), I am using "SAR" (version 2.0.3_, and it only creates a blank page, see here:  http://www.r-bloggers.com/archive/

Comment: The problem is not with either plugins.  I think you have some issues with your theme.  One big problem I see is an improperly declared Doctype and other [Validation](http://bit.ly/9DvWBi) errors.  Switch themes to 2010 and see if you have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

W3 Total Cache just buffers and caches whole output, it has very little interaction with other plugins.

Does it work with W3 disabled?

Had you tried this with [`define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in `wp-config.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Debug) to see if there any error messages?

Common issue with archive plugins is that they run out of available memory.